# Unexpected token error when using PHP with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

Currently I'm struggling to get data loaded from my database to Google Charts, I'm following [this](http://www.voidtricks.com/create-google-charts-from-mysql-db/) tutorial.

I'm trying to load 4 different charts in my webpage. However everytime PHP starts to execute a SQL statement I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Inspect element shows this:
[image: The errors that I get[2]]

I expect it is the same problem with every chart, so I will only post the code of the first chart, that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

      ['Date', 'Visits'],
        <?php 
            $query = "SELECT count(ip) AS count, vdate FROM visitors GROUP BY vdate ORDER BY vdate";

            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

                echo "['".$row['vdate']."',".$row['count']."],";
            }
   ?>

    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Date wise visits'
    };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart"));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

The error will start at the same line as PHP starts, so I expect the problem is related to that. I already tries a few things with CDATA, but that dind't work out.

Changing `<script type="text/javascript">` to `<script type="text/html">` makes the errors disappear, but won't let the script working, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Didn;t you post this same question an hour ago?

Comment: How exactly are you "loading" those files? It looks like perhaps you have `<script>` tags *inside* the script content, which is wrong. It's hard to tell however because what you've posted is incomplete.

Comment: You shouldn't try to create JSON on your own. Use `json_encode()`.

Comment: I refer to my previous question on the thread. Is the file a `.php` or `.html`/other? If you view the source is the PHP present?

Comment: this looks like an exact copy of this http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/154147  did you try that answer?

Comment: It is a .php file ofcourse, you could see that in the included image (stats.php). PHP is ofcourse not visible in source via browser. It also isn't a script tag inside a scrip tag.

Comment: how are you using this, as `http://localhost` or `file:///`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks! The example you posted worked! Many thanks! I didn't came across it when I was searching :D

Comment: What example using `http`? Using `file` would have had the `php` in the source..

Comment: @SmashingJummy you're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *how are you using this, as `http://localhost` or `file:///`? – Fred -ii-
>
>   @Fred-ii- thanks! The example you posted worked! Many thanks! – SmashingJummy*

So the answer to this is that you need to run as `localhost`, not as `file:///` directly in your browser, since `file:///` will not parse PHP directives.

- I had a feeling about that.

Comment: My thought as well on the deleted thread because `<?php` is outputted in the source and unexpected in JS.

Comment: @chris85 same here, but going over their code and other comments, my "Spidey Sense" told me that I had to ask that question. Turns out that that's what it was all along.

Comment: @chris85 However, and looking at [your other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570689/unexpected-token-error-when-using-php-with-javascript#comment70345862_41570689) the OP would have more than likely tell us that they saw "code" rather than being parsed. So you were "bang on" ;-)

Comment: I was running the code with WAMP and localhost, but somehow the first line of code was neccasery $con = mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$db");

Comment: @SmashingJummy Indeed, since you needed to connect to the database in order to process the query.

Comment: I had a seperate connect.php file that worked with every other DB connection, but somehow not with this one.

Comment: @SmashingJummy Are you still having the same problem?

Comment: No, it works fine now. Now I'm busy with making an input field so users can add data to the database so the charts will be interactive :)